# Iterative octree traversal

Tags: visual-c++, octree

I am not able to figure out the procedure for iterative octree traversal though I have tried approaching it in the way of binary tree traversal. For my problem, I have octree nodes having child and parent pointers and I would like to iterate and only store the leaf nodes in the stack. 
Also, is going for iterative traversal faster than recursive traversal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed like binary tree traversal, but you need to store a bit of intermediate information. A recursive algorithm will not be slower per se, but use a bit more stack space for O(log8) recursive calls (about 10 levels for 1 billion elements in the octree). 
Iterative algorithms will also need the same amount of space to be efficient, but you can place it into the heap it you are afraid that your stack might overflow.

Recursively you would do (pseudocode):

```
function traverse_rec (octree):
    collect value  // if there are values in your intermediate nodes
    for child in children:
         traverse_rec (child)
```

The easiest way to arrive at an iterative algorithm is to use a stack or queue for depth first or breath first traversal:

```
 function traverse_iter_dfs(octree):
     stack = empty
     push_stack(root_node)
     while not empty (stack):
         node = pop(stack)
         collect value(node)
         for child in children(node):
             push_stack(child)
```

Replace the stack with a queue and you got breath first search. However, we are storing something in the region of O(7*(log8 N)) nodes which we are yet to traverse. If you think about it, that's the lesser evil though, unless you need to traverse *really* big trees. The only other way is to use the parent pointers, when you are done in a child, and then you need to select the next sibling, somehow.

If you don't store in advance the index of the current node (in respect to it's siblings) though, you can only search all the nodes of the parent in order to find the next sibling, which essentially doubles the amount of work to be done (for each node you don't just loop through the children but also through the siblings). Also, it looks like you at least need to remember which nodes you visited already, for it is in general undecidable whether to descend farther down or return back up the tree otherwise (prove me wrong somebody).

All in all I would recommend against searching for such a solution.

Comment: Is it possible to use the iterative procedure to only store the leaf nodes in the stack instead of the entire tree?

Comment: The solutions above do not store the entire tree in the stack, but only the future choice points, determined by the path you descended (for a tree with depth 10, this would mean at most 10 levels of call stack for the recursive solution or at most 70 nodes for the iterative ones). I am node sure what you mean with "the leaf nodes" - the results perhaps? If you mean all the leaf nodes in your tree: That would most probably blow your stack, as there will likely be a *lot* of them! ;-)

Comment: So I am looking for the region growing algorithm where I have the neighboring nodes. The neighboring nodes might not be leaf nodes in which case I need to get all the leaf nodes of the neighbors. I wanted to have something like
While(temp->hasChild)
 do temp = temp->child
push_stack(temp)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your goal is. Are you trying to find whether a node is visible, if a ray will intersect its bounding box, or if a point is contained in the node?

Let's assume that you are doing the last one, checking if a point is/should be contained in the node. I would add a method to the Octnode that takes a point and checks whether or not it lies within the bounding box of the Octnode. If it does return true, else false, pretty simple. From here, call a drill down method that starts at your head node and check each child, simple "for" loop, to see which Octnode it lies in, it can at most be one.

Here is where your iterative vs recursive algorithm comes into play. If you want iterative, just store the pointer to the current node, and swap this pointer from the head node to the one containing your point. Then just keep drilling down till you reach maximal depth or don't find an Octnode containing it. If you want a recursive solution, then you will call this drill down method on the Octnode that you found the point in.

I wouldn't say that iterative versus recursive has much performance difference in terms of speed, but it could have a difference in terms of memory performance. Each time you recurse you add another call depth onto the stack. If you have a large Octree this could result in a large number of calls, possibly blowing your stack.

Comment: The goal I am looking for is to do a region growing algorithm based on a certain criteria (varies according to application). For that, I want to get the leaf nodes in the stack and check for the criteria. I get the idea though